# Looking for a way to get a total count of items returned from a database query, for use in pagination with knex

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I am currently adding pagination to my back-end models for retrieving articles from a database using knex.  The model has a limit and an offset, but i need to get hold of the total count of rows returned before limit and offset are applied.

I have considered using a separate model to get a count of the articles, but it seems unnecessary.

````
  return connection
    .select(
      "articles.author",
      "articles.title",
      "articles.article_id",
      "articles.topic",
      "articles.created_at",
      "articles.votes"
    )
    .count({ comment_count: "comments.article_id" })
    .from("articles")
    .leftJoin("comments", "articles.article_id", "comments.article_id")
    .groupBy("articles.article_id")
    .orderBy(sort_by || "created_at", order || "desc")
    .limit(limit || 10)
    .offset((p - 1) * (limit || 10))
    .modify(query => {
      if (username) query.where("articles.author", username);
      if (topic) query.where("articles.topic", topic);
    });
};```

Expect to add a total_count property
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to get a count seperately from the query you are executing. Get the count first, and then run the query again with the limit and offset to get the records

```
connection
.select(
  "articles.author",
  "articles.title",
  "articles.article_id",
  "articles.topic",
  "articles.created_at",
  "articles.votes"
)
.count({ comment_count: "comments.article_id" })
.from("articles")
.leftJoin("comments", "articles.article_id", "comments.article_id")
.groupBy("articles.article_id")
.orderBy(sort_by || "created_at", order || "desc")
```